# jsPlumb Endpoint visible: false?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb, invisible

i have a Dynamic generated Flowchart with jsPlumb.
Im saving it to a MySQL database and i need a different view without any edit funktion.

I know how to remove all parts to make them not editable 
but it always shows the Connection Points ( left, right, top, bottom )

How can i make them invisible so that i just see the Connector/Arrow without my Connection Point?

```
sourceEndpoint = {
    endpoint:["Rectangle",{ width:1, height:1}],
    paintStyle:{ 
        fillStyle:"#db0013",
    },
    maxConnections:999,     
    isSource:false,
    isTarget:false,         
    connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub:[10, 25], gap:0, cornerRadius:0, alwaysRespectStubs:false } ],                                              
    connectorStyle:connectorPaintStyle,
    hoverPaintStyle:endpointHoverStyle,
    connectorHoverStyle:connectorHoverStyle,
    dragOptions:{}       
    },
```

Rectangle with width and height = 1 makes it very small, but still visible
how can i make it invis? :)

thx so fa

xQp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two more ways:

1. Use blank endpoint type. [It does not draw anything visible to the user.](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/endpoints.html)
2. Add cssClass to sourceEndpoint options

   ```
   sourceEndpoint = {
   ... other options ...
       cssClass: 'source-endpoint'
   }
   ```

   and css style

   ```
   .source-endpoint svg * {
       fill: transparent;
       stroke: transparent;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no function to get all endpoints, hence you need to get all the elements having endpoints and then for each endpoint of individual element you need to set it's visible to false:

```
var elem = $('.havingEndpoint'); // get elements having endpoint based on its class

for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++)   // for all elements having endpoints iterate
{
     var eps=jsPlumb.getEndpoints($(elem[i]));  //get all endpoints of element
     for(var j=0;j<eps.length;j++)
     {
          eps[j].setVisible(false);   // Set visibility of endpoint to false
     }
 }
```

For more refer API DOC'S:

-> [Getting endpoints for an element](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_getEndpoints)

-> [Setting visibility for endpoint](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/Endpoint.html#method_setVisible)

Answer (score 1):

In current versions there are select methods for connections and endpoints,

> and the return value is an object that supports most operations that
>   you can perform on an Endpoint

See the docs here: http://jsplumb.github.io/jsplumb/querying.html#selectEndpoints

Example, hide all endpoints:

```
jsPlumb.selectEndpoints().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

on http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/endpoints.html I noticed you can add css to an endpoint. Can't you just use css "display:none"?

Comment: tryed it but didnt work maybe ill try again at the php directly instead of the external CSS